# How to make images load faster?

Tags: php, html, image

How can I make these images load faster? I have a loop that displays a profiles pictures and the photos take 1 to 2.5 seconds to load. Not one after another but pretty much all at once. I tried re-sizing with PHP but that didn't really change anything. I am not sure how I can pre-load these images with such a loop. What can I do to increase load performance?

**PHP**

```
$query = "SELECT `photoid` FROM `site`.`photos` WHERE `profileid`='$profileid'";
         try{
    $getphotos = $connect->prepare($query);
    $getphotos->execute();
    while ($array = $getphotos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
         echo '<div id="photo"><img src="photoprocess.php?photo='.$array['photoid'].'"></div>';
    }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**CSS**

```
#photo img {
    max-width:100%; 
    max-height:100%;
}
```

**photoprocess.php**

```
       $photoid = $_GET['photo'];

    $query = "SELECT `ext` FROM `site`.`photos` WHERE `photoid`='$photoid'";
        try{
            $getphotos = $connect->prepare($query);
            $getphotos->execute();
            $array = $getphotos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }   

         $ext = $array['ext'];

        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('userphotos/'.$photoid.''.$ext.'');
        $imagearray = imagejpeg($image, null);

        header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
            echo $imagearray;
```

I also have extension checks as "if statements" but those can't be slowing it down this much.

Comment: What does the rest of the html page look like? Do you have a lot of css or javascript files? The breowser will only load so many at a time and if you have too many they will have to all be downloaded before the images will start loading. You can use the network timeline in your browser's developer tools or plugins to see when each url is downloaded and how long it takes.

Comment: Also in general it is a bad idea to do `<img src="php-file">`. instead you should do `<img src="<?php echo $pathToImage; ?>">`. Static files can be cached by the server and the browser and maybe even the visitor's ISP. PHP files are very hard to cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part

```
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('userphotos/'.$photoid.''.$ext.'');
    $imagearray = imagejpeg($image, null);
```

shouldn't be necessary* and is going to be heavy on the server. You're loading (decoding) and saving (re-encoding) the image for no apparent reason.

Use something like `fpasshtru()`:

```
$name = 'userphotos/'.$photoid.''.$ext.'';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 

fpassthru($fp);
```

Or just link directly to the image. Unless you do some security checks or something, or the images are stored outside the web root, there is no need to go through PHP at all here.

<sub>* = unless you have a very specific use case like removing EXIF data from the stored images. In which case you should use some form of caching.</sub>

Comment: I am not sure what my thought process was when I made that code but I just linked directly to the photos and it is very fast now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are loading image data from disk into an image buffer, which is validated by PHP. After that, you re-encode the image data to a jpg image buffer again and output it. 
This is useless. You can just load an thruput the file (read about [fpassthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php)). This is also much more memory efficient, since the image doesn't need to be entrely loaded in memory entirely at once.

That will be way, way faster, but it can be faster still, because I think you can use just `.htaccess` to redirect an url with an image id to the actual image. You don't even need PHP for that.